# javascript replace multiline string with multiline string

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myString = "lorep ipsum

dummy text1
dummy text2

lorem ipsum."
```

I want to replace `"dummy text1
dummy text2"` with `"xxx"`

I used `text.replace("replace text","value")` but didn't work due to line break on chrome.

I used too many codes but all didn't work on chrome and mac safari

let me know tested solution , please.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lh1vpzjv/1/

Comment: Can you fix the compilation issues in your code?

Comment: the issue is line break if we remove line break it works,

Comment: Please post your actual code. I've deleted my answer because it was based on a misunderstanding of your problem, and that can only be fixed by you posting the actual code and explaining what it's doing wrong in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not define String Like
var myString = "lorep ipsum

dummy text1
dummy text2

lorem ipsum."

For new line you should do like

```
var k="lorep ipsum\n dummy text1\n dummy text2\n lorem ipsum."
var l=k.replace("dummy text1","xxx");
console.log(l);
```